# ImageView setImageBitmap after Crop not working

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

This is my code:

```
File cropImage = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "o_crop_image.jpg");
try {
    if (cropImage.exists()) {
        cropImage.delete();
    }
    cropImage.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
cropUri = Uri.fromFile(cropImage);

Intent i = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
i.setDataAndType(imageUri, "image/*");     //imageUri is the original image
i.putExtra("scale", true);
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, cropUri);
startActivityForResult(i, CROP_PHOTO);
```

And `onActivityResult`:

```
case CROP_PHOTO:
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
     Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cropImage.getAbsoluteFile());
     photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);  //photo is an ImageView
}
break;
```

The code `photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap)` should work, but the ImageView didn't show any picture. the bitmap I get is ok which I can find in the SD.

Even other bitmaps can't be set in the ImageView, but the method `setImageResource` is ok. I there anyone can help ?

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are many [image cropping libraries for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake, I found after I change `i.putExtra("scale", true)` to `i.putExtra("scale", "true")`, the `setImageBitmap` worked. I don't know why but this really solve my problem.